# How do I set google cloud bucket permissions to allow write access?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to export a table from big query into a storage bucket and I am being denied access. I am the owner and this is my only project. What can I do to allow access?

Comment: Can you update your post with the `configuration.extract` job?

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery#access) say, You need to have *READ* access on the Dataset (BigQuery) and have a *WRITE* (or *OWNER*) [permission](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) on the bucket (Cloud Storage).

The bucket you selected for the export already exists?

Using the Storage Browser (the web interface), can you upload a file into that bucket? Do you have the permission to do that?

You can use the Storage Browser from this url

> https://console.developers.google.com/project/your-project-id/storage/browser

Comment: I have owner permission on the bucket, as for the big query I cannot find those permissions

Answer (score 1):

it turns out I had to add the file name at the end of extension, thank you for your answers

Comment: Please consider accepting your own answer to close this question off. Cheers,